# Multiple /faces in URL Breaks Security in JSF application

Tags: jsf, mojarra, java-security

Good day. I have an issue where someone can bypass security by repeating the /faces mapping on the URL. For example if you visit http://myhost/faces/AdminStuff/SecurePage.xhtml, they get sent to the login screen, but if they enter http://myhost/faces/faces/AdminStuff/SecurePage.xhtml, they go straight to the page without authentication. It turns out you can enter 'faces' as many times as you want in the URL.

We are specifying security and the faces servlet in web.xml like this

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<context-param>
    <param-name>facelets.SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_VIEW_MAPPINGS</param-name>
    <param-value>*.html;*.jsf;*.xhtml</param-value>
</context-param>
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>    
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>AdminStuff</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>AdminStuff</web-resource-name>
        <description></description>
        <url-pattern>/faces/AdminStuff/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <description></description>
        <role-name>AdminRole</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<security-role>
    <role-name>AdminRole</role-name>
</security-role>
```

How can I prevent this?
My faces implementation is Mojarra 2.2.8-34.

Comment: This has been around for awhile, but didn't get resolved https://github.com/javaee/mojarra/issues/3210

Comment: I can change the faces url-pattern to <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern> and it solves the issue, but It'll be a major effort to convert all of the links in and around the application. It'd be great to have a solution where /faces works but /faces/faces/faces doesn't.